# Writing Test Case using Mocha and Chai for a function with response.send( )

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm doing testing in node.js for the first time. I've created a simple program below. An html form has two fields, name and age. When a user submits the form, the age is checked in certificate function inside 'ageVerification.js' for it should be more than 18. If age is less than 18, null is returned otherwise some random number. Had the same getAuth function thrown error, then i would test it using 
`expect(auth.getAuth.bind(this,req,{})).to.throw('whatever thrown')`
but if the function is just ended with res.send("some string"), then how to test the function. Thanks in advance.

```
  **code to test**
    const certificate=require('./ageVerification')
    module.exports.getAuth=function(req,res){
    if(certificate.certificate(req.body.ageText)!=null && 
            req.body.uName=='prateek'){
            res.write("Hello Prateek")
            return res.end()
        }

        if(certificate.certificate(req.body.ageText)!=null && 
            req.body.uName!='prateek')
            return res.send("You need to register first")

        if(certificate.certificate(req.body.ageText)==null){
             res.write("You are not of required age")
             return res.end()
        }
   }

 **test case**
const certificate=require('../ageVerification')
const auth=require('../controller')
const chai=require('chai')
const expect=require('chai').expect;
describe("Age field is null",function(){
    it("name is correct",function(done){
        const req={
            body:{
                ageText:null,
                uName:'prateek'
            }
        }
         expect(auth.getAuth.bind(this,req,{})).[I'm stuck here ???]

    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [sinonjs](https://sinonjs.org/) to make stubs for `res.send`, `res.write` and `res.end` methods and assert them have been called or not to check the code logic.

E.g.

`controller.js`:

```js
const certificate = require('./certificate');

module.exports.getAuth = function(req, res) {
  if (certificate.certificate(req.body.ageText) != null && req.body.uName == 'prateek') {
    res.write('Hello Prateek');
    return res.end();
  }

  if (certificate.certificate(req.body.ageText) != null && req.body.uName != 'prateek')
    return res.send('You need to register first');

  if (certificate.certificate(req.body.ageText) == null) {
    res.write('You are not of required age');
    return res.end();
  }
};
```

`certificate.js`:

```js
exports.certificate = function(age) {
  return age;
};
```

`controller.test.js`:

```js
const auth = require('./controller');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('61943894', function() {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should return required age message', function() {
    const mReq = {
      body: {
        ageText: null,
        uName: 'prateek',
      },
    };
    const mRes = {
      write: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      send: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      end: sinon.stub(),
    };
    auth.getAuth(mReq, mRes);
    sinon.assert.calledOnceWithExactly(mRes.write, 'You are not of required age');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mRes.end);
  });

  it('should say hello', () => {
    const mReq = {
      body: {
        ageText: 29,
        uName: 'prateek',
      },
    };
    const mRes = {
      write: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      send: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      end: sinon.stub(),
    };
    auth.getAuth(mReq, mRes);
    sinon.assert.calledOnceWithExactly(mRes.write, 'Hello Prateek');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mRes.end);
  });

  it('should return register message', () => {
    const mReq = {
      body: {
        ageText: 29,
        uName: '',
      },
    };
    const mRes = {
      write: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      send: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      end: sinon.stub(),
    };
    auth.getAuth(mReq, mRes);
    sinon.assert.calledOnceWithExactly(mRes.send, 'You need to register first');
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
  61943894
    ✓ should return required age message
    ✓ should say hello
    ✓ should return register message


  3 passing (34ms)

----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files       |     100 |       90 |     100 |     100 |                   
 certificate.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 controller.js  |     100 |       90 |     100 |     100 | 12                
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```